# Proof with orthogonal vectors in real analysis

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $x$ and $y$ are called perpendicular (or orthogonal) if $\langle x,y\rangle =0$. If $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular, prove that $|x+y|^2=|x|^2+|y|^2$.

Seems pretty basic, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you know that $|v|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$. If you just expand $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle$ by using linearity, you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write out $|x+y|^2$ in terms of the dot product. That is,
$$|x+y|^2 = (x+y)\cdot (x+y) = x\cdot x+2\,x\cdot y+y\cdot y.$$
You should be able to finish it from there.

Comment: This isn't the dot product per se, it's a general inner product (of which the dot product is a particular case).

Comment: The vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the inner product *is* the dot product. It's not really a fair assumption that @Sarah is familiar with generalized inner product spaces.

Comment: the dot product isn't the only inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and she's using the general notation.

Comment: It's the one that gives us the Euclidean norm though, and orthogonality would be very strangely defined if you *weren't* assuming dot product. I think given the context it's a reasonable assumption. (And the general notation point is moot considering it's from *your* edit)

Comment: The proof is fine. It doesn't matter which scalar product is.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Remember that $|x|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$ and use that the inner product is bilinear!

Comment: The inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is not linear.

Comment: @Pp.. potato-potato. I corrected it though.

Comment: Exactly. You pick on the other answers on irrelevant things. Take a little of your own medicine.

Comment: @Pp.. you're right. Constructive criticism is always useful, and it's important to use the right notation and names. For these reasons, my opinion on the other answer holds.

Answer (score 0):

$$\big|x+y\big|^2= \langle x+y,x+y \rangle=\langle x,x+y\rangle+y\langle x+y\rangle$$ $$= \langle x,x \rangle + \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x\rangle+ \langle y,y\rangle$$ $$=\big|x\big|^2+\big|y\big|^2$$

as $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle =0$

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ commands for the brackets are \langle and \rangle